# How to parse an html document into an AST that includes line numbers for each node?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I'd like to use JavaScript to parse an html document into an abstract syntax tree, where each node also includes start and end line numbers (and hopefully also character positions) for each node.  Are there any existing solutions that can do this?  I don't want to have to write it myself.

Edit Apr 24, 2016:  Being able to parse HTML along with php tags in arbitrary places would be even more ideal.

Comment: Did you find something?

Comment: Nope.  For now I'm just using some regexes that handle most cases until I have time to return and write a real parser myself.

Comment: oh ok. I found this: https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/html-parse-stringify, its missing line numbers though so I might try and add that if I have time

Answer (score 5):

https://unifiedjs.github.io/ can get you the CST or AST for a few formats including HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I used [node-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser). It's working like a charm!
Accessing character position easily by 'range' attribute

```
const scripts = parse(code).getElementsByTagName('script')
const pureCode = code.slice(scripts[0].range[0], scripts[0].range[1]);
```